# Why the running time of a mapper should be more than 1 minute?

Tags: hadoop, mapper

I have read from many blogs/web pages that state

> the running time of a mapper should be more than X minutes

I understand there are overheads involved in setting up a mapper but how exactly is this calculated? Why is it after X minutes the overhead then is justified? And when we talk about overheads, what are the Hadoop overheads?

Comment: Could you please provide link where you read this. As it may differ froms scenario to scenario , what is usecase.

Comment: http://www.idryman.org/blog/2014/03/05/hadoop-performance-tuning-best-practices/ I didn't really question it when I first started reading Hadoop materials. The statement makes sense. Then, I wanted to do some performance tuning and started looking deeper. And just realized...I don't really understand the term 'overhead' in Hadoop's context.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a hard code rule but makes sense. At the background so many small process are handled out before a mapper is started. Its initialization,other stuffs apart from the real processing would itself take 10-15 seconds. So to reduce the number of split which in turn would reduce the mapper count, maxsplitsize could be set to some higher value that is what that blog conveys. If we fail to do that. Below are the overheads the MR framework has to handle while creating a mapper.

1. Calculating splits for that mapper.
2. The job scheduler in jobtracker has to create a separarte map task this would increase the latency a bit.
3. When it comes to assignment the jobtracker will have to look for a tasktracker based on its data locality. This will again involving creating local temp directories in the tasktracker which would be used up by the setup and cleanup task for that mapper, for example in the setup the if we are reading from a distributed cache and putting that intop a hashmap or initializing and cleaning up something in the mapper.And if already there are enough map and reduce tasks running in that tasktracker this would put a overhead on the tasktracker.
4. In worst case the number of fixed map task is full, then the JT will have to look for a different TT which would lead to a remote read.
5. Also TT would only send the heartbeat to JT once in 3 seconds this would cause a delay in the job initialization because the TT would have to contact the JT to run a job as well as sending the completed status.
6. Unfortunately if your mapper fails then that task would be run 3 times before it finally fails.